# Dijkstra's Algorithm: backtracking at the end of the algorithm could be $O(|V|^2)$?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

In Dijkstra's Algorithm, it is standard to build up a `predecessors` map while executing the algorithm, setting `predecessors[v] = u` when the standard `D[u] + length(u, v) < D[v]` condition is met and that edge is relaxed. This allows you to, at the end, backtrack starting at a given `target` vertex, following the pointers in `predecessors`, to generate the shortest path from `source` to `target`.

Does the complexity of running this `backtrack` subroutine for all vertices come out to $O(|V|^{2})$?

If so, is there a correct way to return shortest paths from `source` to all other vertices which preserves Dijkstra's Algorithm's $O(|E| + |V|log|V|)$ runtime?

Or does the return format actually have to be this `predecessor` map itself, such that the responsibility of generating shortest paths from the `predecessor` map is on the consumer of the algorithm's output (and if they actually need all shortest paths from `source` then there's no getting around that $O(|V|^2)$, and if they only need some of the shortest paths then they can avoid grabbing all of them by only `backtrack`ing on the ones they need).

Comment: Question sparked because pseudo-code I've read (on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode) and [other](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs2321/www/newLectures/29_Weighted_Graphs_and_Dijkstra's_Algorithm.html)) either returns just the distances, or just the distances and predecessors map, and I'm implementing Dijkstra in Python and currently leaning toward returning a `defaultdict`-like object which generates each path on the fly when it's requested for a certain target vertex, to enable the behavior described above of avoiding the $O(|V|^2)$.)